# Generating a unique data store key from a federated identity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication

I need a unique datastore key for users authenticated via openid with the python 2.7 runtime for the google apps engine.

Should I use `User.federated_identity()` or `User.federated_provider() + User.federated_identity()`?

In other words is `User.federated_identity()` unique for ALL providers or just one specific provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User.federated_identity()` "Returns the user's OpenID identifier.", which is unique by definition (it's a URL that uniquely identifies the user).

Comment: Thanks for responding Nick.  My confusion was with the GAE documentation which states that the User.user_id() will return None for non-google accounts.  At least in my initial (cloud) testing it appeared to return a value for all open id providers.  Since I was using the idiom ".user_id() or .federated_id()" I never saw the actual federated_id value.  I changed my logic to user user_id when on the development server and federated_id otherwise and now I can see that they are obviously unique.